# Why am I getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined in todoapp?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error for some reason in my simple react todo app:
[image: this error]

Any idea how to fix that? I cannot see any mistake and I am a beginner with react framework. I appreciate any help a lot. Thanks so much guys in advance.

I have also added the requested rest of the code so be sure to check that out.

#### App.js

```
 import React, { useState,useRef,useEffect } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import TodoList from './TodoList';
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
    function App() {
      const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'todoApp.todos'
      const[todos,setTodos]=useState([{id:1,done:false,name:"todo1"}]);

      useEffect(() => {
        const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
        if (storedTodos) setTodos(storedTodos)
      }, [])
    
      useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
      }, [todos])
      const myRef=useRef();

      function handleAddTodo(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const name=myRef.current.value;
        if (name==='') return
        setTodos(prevTodos=>{
          return [...prevTodos,{name:name,done:false,id:uuidv4()}]
        })
        myRef.current.value = null
      }

      function toggleTodo(id) {
        const newTodos = [...todos]
        const todo = newTodos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
        todo.done = !todo.done
        setTodos(newTodos)
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <input ref={myRef} type="text"/><button onClick={handleAddTodo}>Add todo</button>
          <TodoList todos={todos} toggleTodo={toggleTodo}/>
        </>
      );
    }
 
    export default App;
```

#### TodoList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

function TodoList({todos,toggleTodo}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {todos.map(todo=>(
  <Todo todo={todo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo}/>
            )
              
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoList
```

#### Todo.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Todo({todo,toggleTodo}) {
    
  function handleTodoClick(id){
    toggleTodo(id)
  }
  
  return (
        <div>
          {todo.name} <input checked={todo.done} type="checkbox" onChange={handleTodoClick}></input> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo
```

Comment: Can you include your `Todolist` component?

Comment: We need to see how did you call the `toggleTodo` function in the TodoList.

Comment: I added it just now

Comment: You don't pass any id to `toggleTodo` function. You can use it in `Todo.js` directly like so `<input checked={todo.done} type="checkbox" onChange={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}></input> `.